# Having issues chaining classes with Jade and CSS

Tags: css, pug, template-engine

Does anyone know of CSS chaining issues with Jade 1.3? When I do the following it just outputs static text.

```
div.red.blue-green
```

I get...

```
<div class="red">blue-green</div>
```

I've also tried...

```
 -var classes = ['red', 'blue-green'];
 div(class=classes)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this without the dash (`bluegreen`) or with escaping the dash? (`blue\-green`)? The Jade documentation suggests that your second example should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was a templating issue with extending different Jade files.